# How to set ActionBar icon for AppTheme Activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

`android:logo` and `android:icon` not working for me.

Comment: try to `clean` the project and `rebuild` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below lines in your layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

And add below code to onCreate() of this activity:

```
ToolBar toolbar=(ToolBar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```